# Does there exist homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z_{24}\to\Bbb Z_{24}$ such that $\phi(14)=15$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

My thoughts:

Since $\Bbb Z_{24}$ is  cyclic, generated by $a=1$ $\phi(14)=14 \phi(a)=15 \mod(24) $.

Does that mean that $\phi(a)$ is the solution of the equation $\phi(a)=14^{-1}15 \pmod{24} $?

Thanks.

Comment: suppose $\phi(14) = 15$, then $0 = 7\phi(24) = \phi(12\cdot 14) = 12 \cdot 15 = 12 \not = 0$

Comment: @ZAF so such homomorphism doesn't exist?

Comment: This statement is false

Comment: There are many homomorphisms from $\Bbb Z/24\Bbb Z$ to itself, not just the identity. Indeed, multiplication by $k$ is a ring homomorphism for any integer $k$, and this leads to $24$ different homomorphisms. There are even $\phi(24)=8$ invertible ring homomorphisms. But there are none satisfying $\phi(14)=15$ as ZAF has noted.

Comment: @GregMartin Can you please help me understand why my proposed solution is false?

Comment: $14$ is not invertible in $\Bbb Z_{24}$.

Comment: @GregMartin Multiplication by an arbitrary $k$ is a homomorphism of additive groups but usually not of rings.

Comment: You're right, I was getting confused about which structure was relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to use additive notation, so $\mathbb{Z}_{24} = \mathbb{Z}/24\mathbb{Z}.$

Suppose $\phi(14) = 15$, then $\phi(14\times12) = 12\phi(14) = 12 \times 15 = 12$. At the same time, $14 \times 12$ is a multiple of $24$, hence $\phi(14 \times 12) = 0$. But $12 \neq 0$.

Comment: I've just realized this is exactly what @ZAF pointed out in his comment on the question.